# Batch script to kill a process if not responding in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, taskkill

I am trying to install some windows standalone update files and to do this I need to use wusu.exe.  Every now and again wusu.exe will hang.  I have created a batch file called prereqs.bat and in this file I have calls to the wusu.exe.  I need the code to kill wusu.exe if it hangs, and retry it again.

This is my code as it stands now:

```
:PreReqs32
taskkill /im prereqs32.bat /f
taskkill /im wusa.exe /f
```

when it loops back, it kills both the batch file and wusa.exe

```
start cmd /k c:\windows\temp\prereqs.bat
```

An outside process so that I can kill wusu.exe if things go awry.

```
timeout /t 240 /NOBREAK
```

this timeout is to wait until the install is complete which is sometimes not enough.

```
taskkill /im "[wusa.exe]" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto PreReqs32
```

Is there a way for some sort of FOR loop, with logic to exit if the status is **not** "not responding"?

Also, as a bonus, is there a way to forgo the timeout and just "wait" for prereqs.bat to be complete before moving on, assuming that wusu.exe has not hung?

Comment: When are people going to understand that, just because it has a black box and blinky white cursor *doesn't mean it is DOS*?!

Comment: I understand the difference between DOS and a Windows Terminal window.  But Windows Terminal Window seemed too long to type.

Comment: Edited title to remove DOS.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here? There's a question as an afterthought at the end, but it starts with "Also". Also what?

Comment: I edited the question to actually reflect a question. Thanks.